# `manualChunks` in rollup cause external libraries's peer dependencies undefined

Tags: reactjs, vite, rollup, rollupjs

So I have the `manualChunks` function as below

```js
const manualChunks = (id) => {
  Array.prototype.isContainedById = function () {
    return isContainsAnyOf(this, id);
  };

  if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
    if (
      [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'react-router-dom',
        'react-router',
        'react-error-boundary',
      ].isContainedById()
    ) {
      return 'react';
    }

    if (
      [
        '@tanstack/react-query',
        '@tanstack/react-query-devtools',
        '@tanstack/react-table',
        '@lukemorales/query-key-factory',
      ].isContainedById()
    )
      return 'tanstack';

    if (['react-hook-form', '@hookform/resolvers', 'yup'].isContainedById())
      return 'hookform';

    if (['@emotion/react', '@emotion/styled'].isContainedById())
      return 'emotion';

    if (
      [
        'i18next',
        'react-i18next',
        'i18next-icu',
        'i18next-browser-languagedetector',
        'i18next-phrase-in-context-editor-post-processor',
      ].isContainedById()
    )
      return 'i18next';

    if (
      [
        'react-dropzone',
        '@dnd-kit/core',
        '@dnd-kit/modifiers',
        '@dnd-kit/sortable',
        '@dnd-kit/utilities',
      ].isContainedById()
    )
      return 'dnd';

    if (['@sentry/react'].isContainedById()) return 'sentry';
    if (['reactflow'].isContainedById()) return 'reactflow';
    if (['@auth0/auth0-react'].isContainedById()) return 'auth0';
    if (['zustand'].isContainedById()) return 'zustand';
    if (['fuse.js'].isContainedById()) return 'fuse';
    if (['axios'].isContainedById()) return 'axios';
    if (['react-signalr'].isContainedById()) return 'react-signalr';
    if (['framer-motion'].isContainedById()) return 'framer-motion';
    if (['dayjs', '@date-io/dayjs'].isContainedById()) return 'date';
    if (['@mui/material'].isContainedById()) return 'mui-material';
    if (['@mui/styles'].isContainedById()) return 'mui-styles';
  }
  const match = /\/src\/i18n\/(?=\S*-?)([a-zA-Z-]+)\//.exec(id);
  if (match) {
    return `locale-${match[1]}`;
  }
  if (id.includes('icomoon/selection.json')) {
    return 'icomoon';
  }
};
```

Everything was built successfully. However, when I enter the web app, the app crashed and show the errors
[image: error]

If I remove the `react` block, it works. What is the reason behind it?